# Using external microphone in Bootcamp

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, microphone

I have an implemented microphone in my headphones *(earbuds)*, Microphone doesn't work at all..

After searching for sometime i found out its a known problem, Bootcamp doesn't recognize external microhphones

- I tried this microphone on OS X using same laptop *( and it works perfectly )*
- I'm using Macbook Air 2013

However i solved it by using **Parallels Desktop 9** as an alternative virtual machine than bootcamp and it works good, **But** thats not the solution I'm looking for, I want to get this external mic to work in bootcamp windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is sorry, but there seem to be no driver to support the external input in the headset. My solution that works is to get a cheap USB to headset audio adapter that support the 4 pin 3,5mm jack of the headsets. Here is one that works, but you can surely find others in your local market:

https://www.wentronic.com/de-en/index/artikel/USB-2-0-sound-card-audio-adapter-headset-adapter-96291

Comment: May you explain how will this solve the problem ? Will it install drivers ? What's the difference, thanks

Comment: Of course, the USB adapter installs as a Windows sound unit and does not rely on the sound card already in your Mac. In my case the drivers was already found by Windows but I guess there might be other similar USB sound cards that need a Windows driver that most likely comes with the unit.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Parallels or VmWare Fusion, your original Mac will load all drivers and on top of that you will run your Windows environment.

There's not really much you can check except clicking the Apple icon (**strong text**) on the left-top of your Mac and check the **About this Mac** followed by **More Info...**

After that click **Audio** and check the manufacturer. In my case this is Apple Inc. as image below describes. I cannot find any other Windows driver for this. I don't know if any Mac has a different kind of built-in mic, but it's worth checking it out.

[image: Built-in microphone]

As you might have noticed already, the drivers for the built-in Microphone is only available for OS X. That's the reason why it doesn't work.